# Determining subnet with DHCP but setting static IP for ending

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

We have a project that uses a raspberry pi as part of a larger device we install on various clients properties, it gets wired up via ethernet, but due to various reasons we need to have the port forwarding setup in advance, and we often don't know if the subnet is 192.168.1 or 10.0.0 or 192.168.0 or whatever before we actually head out and install the device on the clients property. Is there any way that we can configure our Raspberry Pi such that it will determine the first 3 bytes of the IP via DHCP (or otherwise) but still allow me to set the last byte to .42 (or whatever I choose)?

Comment: Can you not just ask the client what subnet they are using?

Comment: When you get to the client site, have the client administrator create a DHCP reservation for the address that you need within their subnet.

Comment: unfortunately these can be difficult, as the clients often do not have an IT person on site, and often do not even know their own router passwords. We can and do have the clients IT team reserve the specific IP we want, but we still need to adjust to their subnet, as they will forward to X.Y.Z.42 for us but we still need to boot up and log into the pi to swap its subnet to X.Y.Z.42 from its static of A.B.C.42, I am hoping to remove that step. Unfortunately, regardless of what subnet we use at the office, we always have clients with different subnets, and we usually don't know them in advance.

Comment: Can't you attempt to set up your portforwarding to not depend on an IP (but rather an interface)?

Comment: Unfortunately we do not set up the port forwarding, we tell the clients IT team that we want ports X to go to ports Y on IPs Z, and they usually get it done within the first 3 tries. But we almost never actually get to log into the clients routers to set the port forwarding. If instead you mean that we could set this on the Pi, I would love some links to resources detailing it, as I believe that is what we want to do, and what I am trying to ask.

Comment: never mind I didn't understand this in the question